# Count clicks on a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have @promoted_products that are posted throughout the site(like ads) and they link to @products.

The goal is to count the number of clicks to a specific product from a promoted_product(ad).

```
<% @promoted_products.each do |promoted_product| %>
 <%= link_to promoted_product.product.name, product_path(promoted_product.product) %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Google Analytics is your best bet.

Comment: Can you please be more detailed and explain how to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really, no. It's a big topic. Google "Google Analytics".

Comment: I know what GA is. How would that help me solve the problem? Is there a better 'from scratch' solution?

Answer (score 1):

Considering link redirect user to show action of product. Then you can add a field count in database and on each show request update count. In this way you can find click counts easily. You can also do it with remote true and check whether request is js or html. In js request update count record and in html do not update count. So you will get exact click count.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to use Google Analytics.

We're developers here - we can make our own stuff!

--

**System**

The way I would do this is to use a controller with either a database, or Redis instance, to provide a "running total" of the clicks for your link:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
Class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :increase_click

   private

   def increase_click
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
      @product.increase_click
   end
end

#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :clicks

   def increase_click
      self.clicks.create!
   end
end

#app/models/click.rb
Class Click < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | product_id | created_at | updated_at -> add more attributes for specific info
   belongs_to :product
end
```

This will give you the ability to add new clicks to the product each time the `ProductsController` is invoked.

You could then call the `clicks` for a product as follows:

```
@product = Product.find params[:id]
@product.clicks.size #-> number of clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker to your code and use google analytics. e.g.:

```
def show
  tracker do |t|
    t.google_analytics :send, { type: 'event', category: 'button', action: 'click', label: 'nav-buttons', value: 'X' }
  end
end
```